# Mongodb find comparing array element to array field

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, find

I'm wondering how I can compare arrays of (nested) objects in Mongoose.

Considering the codebelow, I would like to get results when the pskills properties match. Could anyone help me with this?

```
  ao = await Ao.find({
//req.body.pSkills is arraay //['nodejs', 'angular'..]
                pSkills: { $eq: req.body.pSkills }
          });
```

Comment: What you trying to find exactly? All docs that have exactly the same pSkills as `req.body.pSkilles`? All docs that contain the pSkills in `req.body.pSkilles`? All docs that have at least one pSkill from `req.bodypSkilles`. Providing a scenario is usually helpful.

Comment: Exactly  like this example   document : {name: 'test', pSkills: 'Angular','nodejs,'..]}

Comment: I search document with pSkils  = [nodejs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) to search into an array.

Try this query:

```
ao = await Ao.find({
  "pSkills": {
    "$in": req.body.pSkills
  }
})
```

Check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Wp352OQMVYb) example

Comment: You are welcome. Also if the issue has been solved, to mark the answer as accepted is appreciated.